# How to check for an unsigned BYTE in a 32-bit register in MASM

Tags: assembly, byte, 32-bit, masm

So I have run into a need to validate input such that the user is inputting a 32-bit decimal (unsigned integer) and I need to sanitize and verify if the number exceeds an 8-bit storage location so I can dump the eAx into DL.

Basically, down-converting. I know there are reasons I don't want to do this, and better ways to accomplish it, but I have a very specific need in this instance. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are surely a lot of approaches. My suggestion is `test eax, NOT 0FFh`. The zero flag is set if `EAX` <= 0FFh and cleared if `EAX` > FFh.